# How create table storage with only connection string on powerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-3.0

is it possible create new table storage on azure with only use connection string by PowerShell?

```
Param (
[string]$StorageAccountName,
[string]$StorageAccountKey,
[string]$name
)

Import-Module Azure

$tableName =  $name

$accountCredentials = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials" $StorageAccountName, $StorageAccountKey
$storageAccount = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount" $accountCredentials, $true

$tableClient = $storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()
$table = $tableClient.GetTableReference($tableName)

$table.CreateIfNotExists()
```

not like this way..

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the function correctly. [This suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.createifnotexists.aspx) it needs two parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure PowerShell Cmdlets, there is a [`New-AzureStorageTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806417.aspx) that you can use to create a new table.

Sample Code:

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "accountname" -StorageAccountKey "accountkey"
New-AzureStorageTable -Name "TableName" -Context $storageContext
```